# BindingOperationInfo is null in SoapMessage of CXF

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

I am working on SOAP web services and extended a class from AbstractSoapInterceptor of CXF which overrides

> handleMessage(SoapMessage message)

In this method  i am trying to get BindingOperationInfo, but it is NULL. I am using cxf version 3.1.5 but if i use cxf version 2.7.5 BindingOperationInfo will be having value of operation name.

Please find  the class below,

```
public class SoInterceptor extends AbstractWsHeaderInterceptor {

public SoInterceptor () throws JAXBException {
    super();
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
     Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();
     BindingOperationInfo boi = exchange.getBindingOperationInfo();
     org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint endpoint = exchange.getEndpoint();
     org.apache.cxf.service.Service service =endpoint.getService();

}}
```

BindingOperationInfo  is getting null from the code. Please let  me know if i have missed anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this instead

```
//Get the endpoint
Endpoint endpoint  = message.getExchange().get(Endpoint.class);

//Get the service called
Service service  = message.getExchange().get(Service.class);

//Get the details of the operation
OperationResourceInfo operation = message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
```

Comment: Not working !!  I am using a Filter and added Pre-Stream interceptor too to get getTargetMethod, but its always null

Comment: @shaILU, this code is also tested with CXF 3.1.10 in a `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` obtaining the message using `Message message = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage();`.  You may want to post your own question with the details